# Passing Array as Values in PG-Promise only gets one result

Tags: javascript, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm trying to pass an array of items to a `SELECT` query and get all the rows back with those items.

So far I've got it to work using a `join` method, but I'd prefer to just pass the array and understand what I'm doing wrong. Perhaps I should just use the `join` method?

This works:

```
var values = ['WH12345678','WH22345678']
values = "'" + values.join("','") + "'";
var query = "select * from pups where workorder IN (" + values + ")"
db.any(query)
```

I can't get this to work, tried tons of variations:

Note: It does current "work" in that it return the first item row, but not both.

```
var values = ['WH12345678','WH22345678']
var values = ["WH12345678","WH22345678"]
var query = "select * from pups WHERE workorder IN ($1:list)"
var query = "select * from pups WHERE workorder IN ($1:csv)"
db.any(query,values)
```

Comment: We cannot speculate why it returns just the first row, as you do not show the database methods you use for executing the queries. In any case, you should try to execute the final query directly, like via pgAdmin, and then compare it with results from `pg-promise` methods, and compare them. Then your question might have a meaning, when specifics are available.

Comment: @vitaly-t Is `db.any(query,values)` not the method call you're looking for?

Comment: You need to pass in `[values]`, not `values` to the query, so it is interpreted as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs of `db.any`](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#any):

> the values can be:
>
> - a single value - to replace all `$1` occurrences
> - an array of values - to replace all `$1`, `$2`, ... variables
> - an object - to apply [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters) formatting

Since you passed an array (`['WH12345678','WH22345678']`), the second case applies: `$1` expands to `'WH12345678'` and `$2` (which you're not using in your query) would expand to `'WH22345678'`.

You need to pass an array instead that has your `values` array as its first element and no further elements for other parameters:

```
var values = ["WH12345678","WH22345678"];
var query = "select * from pups WHERE workorder IN ($1:list)";
db.any(query, [values])
//            ^      ^
```

Alternatively, pass an object to use named parameters:

```
var values = ["WH12345678","WH22345678"];
var query = "select * from pups WHERE workorder IN (${values:list})";
//                                                    ^^^^^^
db.any(query, {values})
//            ^      ^
```

Comment: I have corrected the "named-parameter" example, to adhere to [Named Parameters](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#named-parameters) syntax.

Comment: @vitaly-t oops, I didn't actually visit the link… thanks for the update!